# Curried closures in Swift3?

Tags: swift, closures, swift3, currying

Why

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let filtered = arr.filter { $0 < 3 }
```

and why not?

```
let filtered = arr.filter(<3)
```

if I can use operator function:

```
[1,2,3].sorted(by: >)
```

Comment: Because `<` is a function and `<3` is not.

Comment: @MartinR indeed, `<3` is too complex to ever be representable by a function, even a special-purpose one ;)

Answer (score 2):

The signatures of [`Sequence`](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.0/protocol/Sequence):s `filter(...)` and `sorted(...)` are as follows

```
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Iterator.Element]

func sorted(by areInIncreasingOrder: (Self.Iterator.Element, Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Self.Iterator.Element]
```

Both methods expect a closure as their argument; the former one of type `(Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool`, and the latter a one of type `(Self.Iterator.Element, Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool)`. `<` is function fulfilling the latter for `Comparable` types (specifically `(Int, Int) -> Bool` in your example), whereas `<3` isn't a closure at all.

You could define your own function specifically for this purpose (thanks @vacawama)

```
func lessThan(_ value: Int) -> ((Int) -> Bool) {
    return { $0 < value }
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
let filtered = arr.filter(lessThan(3))
print(filtered) // [1, 2]
```

But generally it might be more simple to just supply a closure on the fly to higher order functions such as `filter` and `sorted`.

Comment: @TimVermeulen thanks for the edit, it seems as the declarations listed in Swiftdoc.org:s autogenerated documentation is not quite up to date.

Comment: Swiftdoc isn't made by Apple, it's simply made by someone that parsed the header file of the standard library. The author has let me know that Swiftdoc is outdated because his parser doesn't support some syntax changes, but it should be updated soon. :)

Comment: @TimVermeulen I knew that Swiftdoc is an (awesome) unofficial reference by Nate Cook, but I didn't know the latter, that it's slightly outdated due to his parser. Great to know, thanks!

Comment: If you define `func lessThan(_ value: Int) -> ((Int)->Bool) { return { $0 < value}}` you could let the closure capture the value and then do `let filtered = arr.filter(lessThan(3))`